# parsing the output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell script output  :

```
{
  "parameter": "p1",
  "device": "d1",
  "assignee": "me"
}

{
  "Name": "N",
  "device": "d4"
  }

{
  "alart": "C1"
  }
```

I want to get the first set only :

```
{
  "parameter": "p1",
  "device": "d1",
  "assignee": "me"
}
```

I tried  **ConvertTo-Json** but it doesn't work as I expected.

note: the length of each set can be different each time so I cant hard code the number of selected lines.

```
$output[0..3]
```

the above code will not work in my case

Comment: | select -first 4

Comment: @js2010 I cant hard code the value because the set size can ve different each time I run the script

Comment: The output looks like multiple JSON documents. How is the script emitting them: 3 multiline strings or all individual lines?

Comment: @mklement0  all individual lines

Comment: @mklement0 
they are similar to json format but not exactly the same format, 
because you need to add more brackets { }

Comment: how about `(output) -match "(?s){.*?}"; $Matches[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be to collect the script's output lines (you state that the script emits its output *line by line*) only up until the first *empty* line is encountered, using a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement.

```bash
$firstParagraph = 
  switch (.\yourScript.ps1) {
    ''      { break } # first empty line found; stop processing
    default { $_ }    # non-empty line: pass it through.
  }
```

If you also need to detect *blank*, i.e. *all-whitespace* lines:

```bash
$firstParagraph = 
  switch -Regex (.\yourScript.ps1) {
    '\S'    { $_ }    # non-blank line: pass it through
    default { break } # first blank line: stop processing
  }
```

If there may be no empty or blank lines between the JSON objects *and* you can rely on `}` *on its own line* closing the first object:

```bash
$firstParagraph = 
  switch -Regex (.\yourScript.ps1) {
    '^\s*}\s*$'   { $_; break } # closing line of the first object: emit and stop processing
    '\S'          { $_ }        # other non-blank line: pass it through
    default       { break }     # first blank line: stop processing
  }
```

---

Finally, you can repeatedly try to parse the lines collected so far as JSON, and stop processing once parsing succeeds; note that this solution returns an *object* representing the first JSON object, as returned by [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json):

```bash
$linesSoFar = ''
$firstObject = 
  switch -Regex (.\yourScript.ps1) {
    '}' { # potentially the end of a complete JSON object
      $linesSoFar += "`n" + $_
      # Try to convert from JSON and output the resulting object,
      # if successful.
      ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction Ignore $linesSoFar
      if ($?) { break } # Conversion succeeded, stop processing.
    }
    default { $linesSoFar += "`n" + $_ }   # first blank line: stop processing
  }
```